# Browser compatability issue -NOt working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my work which works good on Firefox and Google Chrome, but it wouldn't work in IE. Can you point out where I'm getting it wrong?

**Scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var contentId = $(this).attr('contentid');
        $.confirm({
            'title': 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message': 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
            'buttons': {
                'Yes': {
                    'class': 'blue',
                    'action': function () {
                        DoDelete(contentId);
                    }
                },
                'No': {
                    'class': 'orange',
                    'action': function () {}
                    // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                },
                'close': {
                    'action': function () {}
                    // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**confirmscript to generate HTML markup**

```
(function ($) {
    $.confirm = function (params) {
        if ($('#confirmOverlay').length) {
            return false;
        }
        var buttonHTML = '';
        $.each(params.buttons, function (name, obj) {
            buttonHTML += '<a href="#" class="button ' + obj['class'] + '">' + name + '<span></span></a>';
            if (!obj.action) {
                obj.action = function () {};
            }
        });
        var markup = [
            '<div id="confirmOverlay">',
            '<div id="confirmBox">',
            '<div id="header">',
            '<div id ="title">',
            params.title,
            '</div></div>',
            '<div id ="textbox">',
            '<p>',
            params.message,
            '</p></div>',
            '<div id="confirmButtons">',
            buttonHTML,
            '</div></div></div>'
        ].join('');
        $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();
        var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
            i = 0;
        $.each(params.buttons, function (name, obj) {
            buttons.eq(i++).click(function () {
                obj.action();
                $.confirm.hide();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
    $.confirm.hide = function () {
        $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What isn't working? How's it supposed to work? What have you tried doing thus far?

Comment: @user, focus on the *what*. We need to know *what* the code is supposed to do, and the results you're getting on Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is conformation Dialog box which gets invoked when i click on a div and script.js gets executed and sends the title and message parameters to the confirmscript which  would generate the HTML mark up ..I'm terribly sorry for the bad communication

Comment: -------------------MY HTML--------------------------------------

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A jQuery Confirm Dialog Replacement with CSS3 | Tutorialzine Demo</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum&amp;subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page">

 PAGE DIV
        
        <div class="item">
ITEM DIV
         
            <div class="delete"></div>
        </div>
       
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The problem here is when i  click on the div that would generate the markup dialog box for IE it wouldn't show up and i do not any warnings when i debug it

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, the first line of your `$('.delete')` handler is:

```
var contentId = $(this).attr('contentid');
```

but your markup for `.delete` is:

```
<div class="delete"></div>
```

(notice the lack of a `contentId` attribute).  Luckily(?) your code doesn't actually seem to use `contentId` :-)

More relevantly, you need to determine which part of your code is breaking (if you had a JS Fiddle of your code I could look, but since you don't you'll have to find out yourself).  I would put an `alert` just before `$.confirm` is called, and then again inside `$.confirm`, to make sure the code is even getting to your plug-in (if not, that's your problem).

If it is, the next question to ask is "is your markup getting added, but not revealed, or is it simply not being added at all".  Either alerts or the IE developer tools should let you inspect the DOM and find out if your markup is being added; if not, that's your problem.  If it is being added, but isn't getting shown, then something is going wrong with your `fadeIn`, and that's your problem.

As a final note, there's a simpler way you could hook up your button events; instead of:

```
var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
        i = 0;
$.each(params.buttons, function (name, obj) {
    buttons.eq(i++).click(function () {
        obj.action();
        $.confirm.hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

you could just do:

```
$('#confirmBox .button').each(function(button) {
    $(button).click(function () {
        params.buttons[$(this).text()].action();
        $.confirm.hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your direction the script is working fine on firefox and chrome, i was able to view the markup and the conformation dialog box was working  but it wouldnt work on IE i did use use jsfiddle and i have added ; where i was missing inspite of this it wouldn't work on IE and I didn't get any warnings , However i did fix it , all i did was place confirm buttons div in the textbox div and i started working on IE ...  so i'm still little confused i'll post my updated code tomm as my system crashed